# Does the 32 bit version of Ubuntu Mate 22.04 run on a Raspberry Pi 3B+?

Tags: raspberrypi

I downloaded the "official" image ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-armhf+raspi.img.xz from this page https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/armhf/jammy/ Yes, I verified the download. I then burned it to a 16 GB MicroSD card using gnome-disks on my CentOS 7 workstation. I use this utility to burn all images - works fine.

When I boot the Pi using the newly imaged MicroSD card I see:

The multi color Pi screen
A black screen for a few seconds
A dark screen with:

Ubuntu MATE
. . . .

then a blank screen again.

The green disk access LED flashes for a minute or so and then goes dark. Nothing more happens. On a previous attempt I got some sort of message about CPU0 being incompatible. I was trying to reproduce that so I could record the exact message. I have tried two cards. Same scenario. Nothing :cry:

Any suggestions?

TIA

KenT

Comment: Yes, [it says](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) "compatible with models: B2, B3, B3+, B4 and 400".

Comment: I know it SAYS it is compatible. That is why I tried it. However, on multiple Pi 3B+ boards, using mutiple MicroSD cards I have yet to get it to boot. That is why I asked to see if anyone else had luck with it. I did run Ubuntu 18.04 Mate on the Pi 3s some years back.

Comment: If you knew, then who wrote the title? It was, apparently, someone who did not know, unless it was you trying to be vague.

Comment: That is known issue. Refer to https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/changelog/ [ubuntu mate 22.04 new feature & known issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWefV.png)

Answer (score 0):

On Known Issues:

The Pi 2 and Pi 3 will boot to a black screen with the 32-bit ARM (armhf) build 
Simply change dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d to dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d in config.txt to remedy the issue.
22.04.1 is due in August 2022 and this issue will be fixed in those refreshed images.
6 November 2021 - 21.10

What I did:
From the image that was burnt into my SD card using Etcher or (Raspberry Pi Imager) you should navigate to the config.txt file. It's better to use windows because you can quickly navigate through the files in this bootable SD drive and edit them. Then simply look for the  text dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d and change it to  dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d.

Make sure that you save the new conf.txt.
Put the SD back into your Raspberry Pi and it should work now.

They will fix this issue in the next release so my answer will be irrelevant soon. :)